# Nginx Relative URL to Absolute Rewrite Rule?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Given the following config:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name site.com;

    location /proxy {
            proxy_pass   http://newsite.com/;
   }
 }
```

The page hosted on site.com uses relative path `(/main.css)` for all it statics files, so when i receive the proxied page, the browser is querying static files with the wrong path:

i.e. : http://site.com/main.css

How would i go to have these static files requested follow to their original location (http://newsite.com/main.css)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use a [rewrite rule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite) in your `server` section, something like the following (untested):

```
server_name site.com;
rewrite ^/([^/]+\.css)$ http://newsite.com/$1;
```

That should redirect all requests for .css files in the top-level directory of site.com to http://newsite.com/. Adjust the regex or add rewrite rules as necessary if you need to include other static files (images, scripts, etc.).