# proxying relative urls with nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, webserver, reverse-proxy

My question is similar to [Nginx Relative URL to Absolute Rewrite Rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396865/nginx-relative-url-to-absolute-rewrite-rule) - but with an added twist.

I have nginx acting as a proxy server, which proxies for multiple apps, similar to this (simplified) config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  location /app1 {
    proxy_pass   http://app1.com;
  }
  location /app2 {
    proxy_pass http://app2.com;
  }
}
```

This works fine, but as in the other question, these applications (`app1` and `app2`) use relative urls such as `/css/foo.css`, or `/js/bar.js`. Also it's a big problem to ask all applications to change to something like `/app1/css/foo.css`.

Is it possible for nginx to intelligently figure out which application should handle the request? FTR, users would be accessing these applications like this:

`http://example.com/app1/fooaction` or `http://example.com/app2/baraction`.

If it matters, all applications are Java/Tomcat based apps.

TIA!

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit more what you are trying to achieve? Do you want to pass the request "/css/foo.css" to app1 and "/js/bar.js" to app2?

Comment: Yes. If app1 requests for /css/foo.css, it should be proxied to app1.com/css/foo.css. If app2 requests for /js/bar.js, it should be proxied to app2.com/js/bar.js.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your updated comments; 
**if the upstream backend sends the referer header**, you could do something like this:

```
location ~* ^/(css|js)/.+\.(css|js)$ {            
        #checking if referer is from app1            
        if ($http_referer ~ "^.*/app1"){
            return 417;
        }    

        #checking if referer is from app2
        if ($http_referer ~ "^.*/app2"){
            return 418;
        }    
    }
    error_page   417  /app1$request_uri;
    error_page   418  /app2$request_uri;


    location /app1 {        
         proxy_pass  http://app1.com;
    }

    location /app2 {
        proxy_pass http://app2.com;
    }
```

For example, if the backend on app2.com, requests the test.css like this:

```
curl 'http://example.com/css/test.css' -H 'Referer: http://app2.com/app2/some/api'
```

The request land here:

```
/app2/css/test.css
```

Comment: I dont think you got my question clearly. If app1 requests for `/css/foo.css`, it should redirect to `http://app1.com/css/foo.css`. However, if app2 requests for `/css/foo.css` it should go to `http://app2.com/css/foo.css`

Comment: then how `app1` and `app2` are identified in the request? By user-agent? header (referrer?) or a request param? Please provide more details...

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear. App1 is identified by location. So users would type `example.com/app1/fooservice`. BUT the downstream application for app1 uses relative URLs for resources, such as `/css/bar.css` and NOT `/app1/css/bar.css`. Is the problem clear now? FWIW a solution from nginx alone may not be possible here.

Comment: Thank you - this looks promising - I will try and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating subdomains for these apps.

I was trying to run multiple web apps on my home server behind nginx and ran into a similar challenge. Web apps would look for files within relative path.

I use pihole as my DNS. Created DNS entry for my host (with docker containers/ web-apps). Pointed subdomains to DNS of this host.

In nginx.conf, I set location as "/" and used proxy_pass to IP:Port

Follow instructions in https://www.munisso.com/2020/03/30/cnames-on-pi-hole/

**Note**: For the version of pinhole I was, dnsmasq configs had to be placed in /etc/dnsmasq.d/